# Overriding a variable value for a specific element

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I have a small project, where i first tried `Zurb Foundation` framework, heavily using SASS variables for customization, and i got one problem.

I use their `block-grid` extensively, and i need to change `$block-grid-default-spacing:` variable value to  `rem-calc(2)`, but only inside a `#gallery` element, and leave it at default value elsewhere.

If it helps, i use simple code for my gallery (with some irrelevant Smarty templating)

```
<section id="gallery-container" class="row">
    <ul id="gallery" class="clearing-thumbs small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-4" data-clearing>
        {foreach from=$offer->photos->get() item=photo}
            <li>
                <a href="{$photo->image->thumb()}"><img src="{$photo->image->thumb(true, 295, 230, 5)}" alt="{$offer->title->get()}"/></a>
            </li>
        {/foreach}
    </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs on the Foudation page, I think they have a mixin that is available to create your own block-grid. The following was take from http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html:

```
.your-class-name {
    @include block-grid(
        // This controls how many elements will be on each row of the block grid. Set this to whatever number you need, up to the max allowed in the variable.
        // Available options: 1-12 by default, and false.
        $per-row: 3,

        // This controls how much space is between each item in the block grid.
        // Use a variable or any pixel or em values.
        $spacing: $block-grid-default-spacing,

        // This controls whether or not base styles come through, set to false to leave out.
        $base-style: true
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really helped in solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using `block-grid` mixin turned out to be a great idea that solved my problem. That's how my code looked like in the end:

```
#gallery
  @media #{$small-up}
    +block-grid(2, rem-calc(3))

  @media #{$medium-up}
    +block-grid(3, rem-calc(3))

  @media #{$large-up}
    +block-grid(4, rem-calc(3))
```